What Aluminium can weld to 7005, and without subsequent heat treatment?
I'm in Australia, so options are limited.  I'm repairing an adult tricycle frame, so not a high volume enterprise.
The section to repair or replace is 49mm wide x 60mm deep x 2mm wall thickness, 42cm long, rounded corners, and the manufacturer says it is 7005 Al.  It is the horizontal section between the rear cross-member and the hinge under the seat in this picture: Magnum BW side view
I don't have a workshop, and I'm at the mercy of the local help.  My best source is a bicycle frame builder here, and he likes welding 7005 with 5083 rod.
So, first, what reliably welds to 7005?  As an amateur repairing, I don't think I can find a facility with a big enough oven to treat the part after (it's about a meter long minimum).  Please answer in light of that.
Next, it's been a very long time since I did my engineering studies, and I have worked with computers most of my life, so a dumb question.  If I find a rectangular section of about the same or larger than the above, but triple the wall thickness, but, say, half the strength (because it can't be heat treated, for instance) will it be strong enough due to the increased wall thickness?  I don't care about the weight - I can lose a few kilos.
Even if you want to jump to some other suggestion, please address the questions I'm asking above, so I can reason about the situation.  Otherwise I can't come to a conclusion about your ideas, or engage with local welders.
Thanks for help.

Asking for suppliers is making your question off-topic on here. Also, find out who makes things using ally and ask them for offcuts, unless you want a 7 metre standard length...

Can't the bicycle frame builder answer all those questions?  It seems like he's experienced, local, and involved in exactly the kind of work you need to do.
